# Using redis in spring boot application with separate IdP server

Tags: spring-boot, redis, session-management

I have a spring boot application which logs in by making a call to an `IdP` server. I receive a token from this `IdP` server when the login is successful.

This token has to be used for all further interactions till the user logs out or the session expires.

I'm trying to use `Redis` for session management and all the tutorials do not give a explanation as to how this works.

My question is, how do I use `Redis` to store the generated token and how do I retrieve it? Does `Redis` handle this internally or does `Redis` generate its own token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is a **key-value cache structure**. So for your case, you only need to store in redis a pair of key-value for each session as:

> key is the session id
>
> value is the token

On session initiation and a successful login you store the pair. During the session you can access the cache to validate the token. Don't forget to free the cache on logout or session time out.

Comment: Will the `redis` server try to authenticate on its own? If so, is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: NO. You save the token that received from `IdP` server to Redis. Redis don't use its own token.